# vba, how to import values from several excel files (selected by users via dialog box) into a master excel file?

Tags: excel, import, vba

I am quite new with VBA and trying to create a VBA which copy/paste specific ranges from multiple files (.xlsm) selected by a user into a master excel file. Basically I want to summarize the results for different scenarios into one excel file.

Until now, I have searched abit and managed to write a code which asks the files to be important. My problem is: I cant activate those files and start copy/pasting specific values into the master file.

I really appreciate if you can help me solve this. If you have a different idea, then it is also welcome. Many thanks..

```
Sub GetImportValues()
Dim finfo As String
Dim filterindex As String
Dim title As String
Dim filenames As Variant
Dim I As Integer

'Set up list of file filters
finfo = "Excel VBA files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm,"

filterindex = 1

'Set the dialog box caption
title = "pls select the excel files to Import"

'Get the filename
filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(filenames) Then

'Display full path and name of the files
    Msg = "You selected:" & vbNewLine

    For I = LBound(filenames) To UBound(filenames)
    Msg = Msg & filenames(I) & vbNewLine
    Next I
    MsgBox Msg

Else
    MsgBox "No excel file was selected."
End If


' start copy/pasting files one by one

For I = 1 To 10
Workbooks.Open filenames

Sheets("Report Tables").Range("D3").Select
Copy.Range (Selection.Offset(0, 11))
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Activate
Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub GetImportValues()    
    Dim filenames, f
    Dim myMsg As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long        
    'Get the filename
    filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel VBA files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
                                            filterindex:=1, _
                                            title:="pls select the excel files to Import", _
                                            MultiSelect:=True)        
    If IsArray(filenames) Then
        myMsg = "You selected:" & vbNewLine
        'Display full path and name of the files
        For Each f In filenames
            myMsg = myMsg & f & vbNewLine
        Next f
        MsgBox myMsg
    Else
        MsgBox "No excel file was selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each f In filenames
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
            'determine last non empty row in column A sheet "Result" to past result
            lastrow = Application.Max(3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Range("A" & lastrow).Value = wb.Sheets("Report Tables").Range("O3").Value
        End With

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next f
End Sub
```

Code above copies cell `O3` from each workbook and paste it in `Result` sheet of `ThisWorkbook` in `A3` for first file (actually it finds last non empty row), in `A4` for second file and so on